# EF Core migration No Context Type found in assembly

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-3.0, ef-core-3.0

I have a single .net core 3.0 project and added EF core to it. I am trying to add a new migration but getting the following error:

```
The context type '' was not found in the assembly ''.
```

However, migration was enabled as you can see in the screen shot.

[image]

I am not sure what is causing this issue, I also tried running the Enable-Migrations command again with the context name

Comment: `Enable-Migrations` is EF6 command. [Make sure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/powershell#verify-the-installation) you have EF Core PMC tools installed.

Comment: thanks for the help - I added the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools package and it works

Comment: also - i also removed EF 6 from the project, so do not run into confusions